# How to pass an instance of a class into attributes within its constructor and have those attributes access initialized attributes?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

say I have 3 classes in python foo,bar and baz as follows:

```
class Foo(object):
    a=9
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar= Bar(Foo)
        self.baz = Baz(Foo)

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self,Foo):
        self.a = Foo.a

    def f(self,b):
        return self.a*b

class Baz(object):
    def __init__(self,Foo):
        self.b = Foo.bar.f(8)
        print(self.b)

k=Foo()
```

Doing it as such raises the error:

> AttributeError: type object 'foo' has no attribute 'bar'

unsure how to proceed as I would like to pass in that class's instance of itself into the constructors of other classes and have those instance attributes accessible by others within the constructor. I have looked around but unfortunately have not found something similar in nature within the scope of python

Comment: `f` is an instance method; you need an instance of `bar` as the first argument: `foo.bar().f(8)`, or `foo.bar.f(some_instance_of_bar, 8)`.

Comment: Or, you need an instance of `foo` which *does* have an attribute named `bar`: `foo().bar.f(8)`. Your naming scheme makes this unnecessarily confusing. Stick with the convention of capitalizing class names. `class Foo: ...`, `class Bar:...`, etc.

Comment: @chepner but would that instance of bar be that instance of initialized within foo ? sorry for the naming convention I have edited it now

Comment: You are passing the class `foo` to both `bar` and `baz` in `foo.__init__`. The only instance of `foo` you create is in the last line. `bar` simply is not a *class* attribute of `foo`; it's an *instance* attribute of an instance of `foo`.

Comment: Now, `foo` isn't even defined in your definition of `Foo.__init__`.

Comment: @chepner I am really sorry it's late at night here where i am and my head is a bit foggy  sorry for the multiple edits, hopefully it should be right now, thank you for trying to understand me here. so changing it as such as within your first comment should make it work?

Comment: Ok, the point still stands. The class `Foo` *does not have* an attribute named `bar`. You are confusing it with the attribute that `Foo.__init__` sets on an *instance* of `Foo`. It's not clear what you want to do, so I don't know whether you want to adjust the definition of `Baz.__init__` somehow, or if you want to get an instance of `Foo` from somewhere to pass to `Bar` and `Baz`.

Comment: The code is too abstract to make any other useful suggestion.

Comment: You're calling Foo.bar, there is no class method bar in Foo

Comment: @chepner i want to pass in an instance of `Foo` into  `Bar` and `Baz` and have them instance attributes set by `Foo.__init__`  such that these would only be an instance of  the `Foo` class. say for instance i have two instance of  `Foo` say `foo1` and `foo2` and those two foos should have their own instances of `Bar` and `Baz`.

Comment: @geckos so wait so it considers `bar` in `Foo.bar` as a method of `Foo` rather accessing the initialized instance of `Bar` in  `self.bar` after creating an instance of  `Foo` as in `k` in the last line?

Comment: Ah, ok. I think I got what you want.

Comment: @chepner  just an extension: the instance of  `Baz`  of `self.baz` in `foo1` should be able to access the instance of `Bar` of `self.bar` in `foo1` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass `self` (the instance of `Foo` being initialized) to `Bar` and `Baz`, not the class `Foo` itself.

```
class Foo(object):
    a=9
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar(self)
        self.baz = Baz(self)
```

If this is correct, then running your code should produce the output `72`.